# What does "One hop per time interval " mean in the following statements?

Tags: java, c

> Write a program that simulates a computer network using discrete time.
>
> The first packet on each router queue makes one hop per time interval.
>   Each router has only a finite number of buffers. If a packet arrives
>   and there is no room for it, it is discarded and not retransmitted.
>   Instead, there is an end-to-end protocol, complete with timeouts and
>   acknowledgement packets, that eventually regenerate the packet from
>   the source router.
>
> Plot the throughput of the network as a function of the end-to-end
>   timeout interval, parameterized by error rate.

Comment: You simulate in discrete time. In each "time step", the packets move exactly one hop.

Comment: Means a packet can travel between two and only routers in a time unit.

Comment: This question seems off topic; about the semantics of a posed question and not about any technical details

Comment: This isn't the place to ask about the meaning of english words --- and I don't see how to word it differently. The concrete time interval is unspecified, it doesn't matter -- if that's what you don't understand. Anyways: **off-topic**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question isn't even remotely about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if you're confused about the directions you should ask whoever wrote the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a few assignments kind of like this in the past.  My best guess is that "hop" signifies transfer from one node in the network to another, and that "time interval" is arbitrary, and essentially represents an update cycle for the entire network.